# Dynamic multi-input select dropdown failed to take multiple inputs after changing <options> by DOM properties

Tags: javascript, html, oop

I have been trying to make a dynamic multi-input select dropdown, which changes its options of the 
HTML for `MultiSelect` Tag Input. Now My question is when I change the options list by DOM methods as in set_pref_list function. My Input tag loses its styling and `Mutliselect` ability.

Below in the Image, Teaching and Photography were the elements I added earlier, while 'Test Prep' was added after calling the `set_pref_list` function.

[image]

```
    <multi-input>
      <input name="TypeList" list="TypeList" id="input">
      <datalist id="TypeList">
          <option value="1" ></option>
      </datalist>
    </multi-input>
```

Script

`set_pref_list` is a function on a element which changes the dropdown options in multiInput Select.
This is what I tried.

```
   function set_pref_list(prop){
      console.log(prop.id);
      var id = prop.id;
      console.log(multiInput.datalist)
      $("#TypeList").empty();
      for( var i = 0; i < pref_dict[id].length; i++ )
        { 
          $("#TypeList").append('<option value="'+ pref_dict[id][i] +'" />');
        };
        multiInput.datalist = $('datalist')[0];
    };
```

I am also using a `helper.js` (which is I think to extend the Multiput class and adding relevant methods )

```
class MultiInput extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.innerHTML +=
            `<style>
    multi-input input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
      display: none;
    }
    /* NB use of pointer-events to only allow events from the × icon */
    multi-input div.item::after {
      color: black;
      content: '×';
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 18px;
      pointer-events: auto;
      position: absolute;
      right: 5px;
      top: -1px;
    }

    </style>`;
        this._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
        this._shadowRoot.innerHTML =
            `<style>
    :host {
      border: var(--multi-input-border, 1px solid #ddd);
      display: block;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    /* NB use of pointer-events to only allow events from the × icon */
    ::slotted(div.item) {
      background-color: var(--multi-input-item-bg-color, #dedede);
      border: var(--multi-input-item-border, 1px solid #ccc);
      border-radius: 2px;
      color: #222;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: var(--multi-input-item-font-size, 14px);
      margin: 5px;
      padding: 2px 25px 2px 5px;
      pointer-events: none;
      position: relative;
      top: -1px;
    }
    /* NB pointer-events: none above */
    ::slotted(div.item:hover) {
      background-color: #eee;
      color: black;
    }
    ::slotted(input) {
      border: none;
      font-size: var(--multi-input-input-font-size, 14px);
      outline: none;
      padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px; 
    }
    </style>
    <slot></slot>`;

        this.datalist = this.querySelector('datalist');
        this._allowedValues = [];
        for (const option of this.datalist.options) {
            this._allowedValues.push(option.value);
        }

        this._input = this.querySelector('input');
        this._input.onblur = this._handleBlur.bind(this);
        this._input.oninput = this._handleInput.bind(this);
        this._input.onkeydown = (event) => {
            this._handleKeydown(event);
        };

        this._allowDuplicates = this.hasAttribute('allow-duplicates');
    }

    // Called by _handleKeydown() when the value of the input is an allowed value.
    _addItem(value) {
        this._input.value = '';
        const item = document.createElement('div');
        item.classList.add('item');
        item.textContent = value;
        this.insertBefore(item, this._input);
        item.onclick = () => {
            this._deleteItem(item);
        };

        // Remove value from datalist options and from _allowedValues array.
        // Value is added back if an item is deleted (see _deleteItem()).
        if (!this._allowDuplicates) {
            for (const option of this.datalist.options) {
                if (option.value === value) {
                    option.remove();
                };
            }
            this._allowedValues =
                this._allowedValues.filter((item) => item !== value);
        }
    }

    // Called when the × icon is tapped/clicked or
    // by _handleKeydown() when Backspace is entered.
    _deleteItem(item) {
        const value = item.textContent;
        item.remove();
        // If duplicates aren't allowed, value is removed (in _addItem())
        // as a datalist option and from the _allowedValues array.
        // So — need to add it back here.
        if (!this._allowDuplicates) {
            const option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value = value;
            // Insert as first option seems reasonable...
            this.datalist.insertBefore(option, this.datalist.firstChild);
            this._allowedValues.push(value);
        }
    }

    // Avoid stray text remaining in the input element that's not in a div.item.
    _handleBlur() {
        this._input.value = '';
    }

    // Called when input text changes,
    // either by entering text or selecting a datalist option.
    _handleInput() {
        // Add a div.item, but only if the current value
        // of the input is an allowed value
        const value = this._input.value;
        if (this._allowedValues.includes(value)) {
            this._addItem(value);
        }
    }

    // Called when text is entered or keys pressed in the input element.
    _handleKeydown(event) {
        const itemToDelete = event.target.previousElementSibling;
        const value = this._input.value;
        // On Backspace, delete the div.item to the left of the input
        if (value === '' && event.key === 'Backspace' && itemToDelete) {
            this._deleteItem(itemToDelete);
            // Add a div.item, but only if the current value
            // of the input is an allowed value
        } else if (this._allowedValues.includes(value)) {
            this._addItem(value);
        }
    }

    // Public method for getting item values as an array.
    getValues() {
        const values = [];
        const items = this.querySelectorAll('.item');
        for (const item of items) {
            values.push(item.textContent);
        }
        return values;
    }
}

window.customElements.define('multi-input', MultiInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
After a decent amount of time with chrome debugger, I realised that my multiInput.allowed_values list is not re-initializing. So, the solution was to create a simple public method to set new allowed values